# Git merge error: cannot run Sublime_Text_2: No such file or directory

Tags: macos, git, merge, terminal, commit

I'm on my hot fix branch, and I just did git add ., and git commit -m "added well style"

Then I did:

```
johns-mbp:blackjack johncurry$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
johns-mbp:blackjack johncurry$ git merge hotfix
Auto-merging views/stay.erb
error: cannot run Sublime_Text_2: No such file or directory
error: unable to start editor 'Sublime_Text_2'
Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
johns-mbp:blackjack johncurry$ git commit -m "added well style"
[master 91c3bfd] added well style
```

Then I pushed to github on my master branch and everything worked as if it merged successfully, and on github I even have the updates i did to the hot fix branch and merged exactly like I want.  The following part is alarming to me though, what is up with this and how do I get rid of it?

```
  error: cannot run Sublime_Text_2: No such file or directory
  error: unable to start editor 'Sublime_Text_2'
  Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
```

Answer (score 2):

You have probably set your `core.editor` configuration variable (or else the environment variable `GIT_EDITOR`) to `Sublime_Text_2`.  It should be set to `subl -w` or `subl -n -w` (depending on whether you want Sublime to open a new window or not).  `subl` is the command-line tool that comes with Sublime Text.

The relevant part of my global `.gitconfig` file looks like this:

```
[core]
    editor = subl -n -w
```

See http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html for information on setting up `subl`.